# Enumerate giving back letters as value instead of words

Tags: python

I have been given a txt file, where I have to read in a specific line. This line contains the following data:

```
# STN,YYYYMMDD,DDVEC,FHVEC,   FG,  FHX, FHXH,  FHN, FHNH,  FXX, FXXH,   TG,   TN,  TNH,   TX,  TXH, T10N,T10NH,   SQ,   SP,    Q,   DR,   RH,  RHX, RHXH,   PG,   PX,  PXH,   PN,  PNH,  VVN, VVNH,  VVX, VVXH,   NG,   UG,   UX,  UXH,   UN,  UNH, EV24
```

Now the question is to give back the value with the corresponding column index. However, when I try this with enumerate, it gives me a number with only 1 letter at a time. I think this is due to the type of the data, since it is not in between ', but I tried changing it and I can't get to that. I also tried splitting the data, but then it gives me a letter per line. Can someone please help?

```
data = (the line above)

for counter, value in enumerate(data):
         print(counter, value)
```

OUTCOME: 0 #, 1 , 2 S, 3 T, 4 N etc.

This is what I get with the enumerate function. Is there a way to let this function take the , as a delimiter?

Comment: Did you mean: `for counter, value in enumerate(data.split(',')):`?

Comment: Please update your question with your required output.

Comment: What do you mean by saying that the data  "is not in between ' "? The behavior that you describe only makes sense when it *is* all in one string.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much quamrana. for counter, value in enumerate(data,split(',')): indeed worked. I've been stuck on this for 2 hours.

Answer (score 1):

Now the data is a string and when you are enumerating a string it enumerates character by character. If you want to get the words then you have to pass a list by splitting the string with ',' as below. When you are enumerating a list it will take each words as an item. You have to enumerate list and not a string as shown below.

```
data = '# STN,YYYYMMDD,DDVEC,FHVEC,   FG,  FHX, FHXH,  FHN, FHNH,  FXX, FXXH,   TG,   TN,  TNH,   TX,  TXH, T10N,T10NH,   SQ,   SP,    Q,   DR,   RH,  RHX, RHXH,   PG,   PX,  PXH,   PN,  PNH,  VVN, VVNH,  VVX, VVXH,   NG,   UG,   UX,  UXH,   UN,  UNH, EV24'

for counter, value in enumerate(data.split(',')):
         print(counter, value)
```

Here `data.split(',')` will return a list with each words as an item for enumeration.

Comment: The # is part of string.